# Given 4 inputs (A,B,C,D) how can I design a circuit that counts the number of 1s?

Tags: digital-logic, adder

The question is in the title.

If I have 4 inputs, how can I count the number of 1s using full/half adders and produce the binary equivalent of how many 1s exist in the 4 inputs?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Do you know how to make an n-bit (ripple carry) adder from full adders ? You can construct a 2-bit adder from the full adders and chain them to add up the four input lines.

Comment: Are you allowed to use ONLY half/full adders ? Are gates and flip flops allowed ?

Comment: A single full adder has three inputs, and the output is the count of how many of them are "1". You just need to extend this concept to add the fourth input.

Comment: I am allowed to use you gates and half/full adders, no FlipFlops. Yes, i can understand that if you have 3 bits you can use the Full Adder to get the result but given 4 bits, I just don't seem to achieve the same result..

Comment: To add to what @DaveTweed said, a full adder gives a two bit result from the first three inputs. You need to now add the fourth input to this two bit result. For that you need a 2bit adder which can be constructed by connecting full adders. See my previous comment. [To help you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Adders_supporting_multiple_bits)

Comment: I figured out the solution with your help as well. I posted in the answers

Comment: is there any chance that you can make the circuit without using any adders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: The solution.]
Basically figured it out myself and with the comments... You need to count the 3 bits with the full-adder and then use 2 half adders to add the sum of the 3 bits and the 4th bit and then another half adder for the 2 carries.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the problem as adding together four 1-bit numbers. The sum can range from 0 to 4, so you'll need a 3-bit result.

A single full-adder adds together three 1-bit numbers, producing a 2-bit result that ranges from 0 to 3. Now you need to add a fourth 1-bit number to that result. What's the simplest way to do that?

Show us what you've got so far, and we can offer more specific guidance.

Comment: Thank you, I worked it out well and posted in the answers